# Getting the Total Amount by grouping into month in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to write a SQL query in Entity Framework so as to get the total expense amount in array format (i.e I need to group the amounts month-wise).

I have tried this Entity Framework query but it didn't work out:

```
double[] Amountdate;

using (IncomeExpenseManagementDBEntities incomeExpenseManagementDB = new IncomeExpenseManagementDBEntities())
{
    Amountdate = incomeExpenseManagementDB
                     .Expenses
                     .Select(e => e.Amount)
                     .Where(e => e.userID == IncomeExpenseTool.user.Id)
                     .GroupBy(e => e.Date.Month);
}
```

Appreciate any input into this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the Select last and then you'll need to aggregate the value by taking the Sum.

```
var amountsByMonth = incomeExpenseManagementDB.Expenses
    .Where(e => e.userID == IncomeExpenseTool.user.Id)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Date.Month)
    .Select(grp => new 
    { 
        Month = grp.Key, 
        TotalAmount = grp.Sum(x => x.Amount) 
    })
    .ToList();
```

That will result in the sum of the amount for each month that is represented in your DB (in other words if you have no data for the month of March you will not get a result for March).

Comment: If I Console.WriteLine(amountsByMonth);   it didn't print the result. Instead it prints like below
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[Date]) AS [K1], 
            [Extent1].[Amount] AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Expenses] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[userID] = @p__linq__0
        )  AS [Filter1]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]. 
do you have any idea.

Comment: @Senthuran Put a `ToList` at the end to materialize the query.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try this and let you know the outcome